# how to automatically generate hierarchical menus from hierarchy of pages?

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu, hierarchical, breadcrumb

I have a photo site, and I take care to crested a logical nested hierarchy of pages.

e.g. for photos I just posted, I created the following pages:

site.com/2013/
site.com/2013/colorado/
site.com/2013/colorado/crested-butte/

the last of these is the one on which I placed my photos.

I want hierarchical menus that are easy to navigate/browse. How do I instruct Wordpress to automatically generate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) function will generate a hierarchical list of pages for you.